# Using count occurrences of a string in a pandas series

Tags: python, string, pandas, count, series

I have a pandas series of lists with collection of words in them.I am trying to find frequency of a particular word in each list  For e.g.,
the series is

```
0    [All, of, my, kids, have, cried, nonstop, when...
1    [We, wanted, to, get, something, to, keep, tra...
2    [My, daughter, had, her, 1st, baby, over, a, y...
3    [One, of, babys, first, and, favorite, books, ...
4    [Very, cute, interactive, book, My, son, loves...
```

I want to get count of kids in each row. I have tried

```
series.count('kids')
```

Which gives me an error saying 'Level kids must be same as name (None)'

```
series.str.count('kids)
```

gives me NaN values.

How should i go about getting the counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [5288]: series.apply(lambda x: x.count('kids'))
Out[5288]:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: s, dtype: int64
```

---

Details

```
In [5292]: series
Out[5292]:
0    [All, of, my, kids, have, cried, nonstop, when]
1    [We, wanted, to, get, something, to, keep, tra]
2    [My, daughter, had, her, 1st, baby, over, a, y]
3      [One, of, babys, first, and, favorite, books]
4    [Very, cute, interactive, book, My, son, loves]
Name: s, dtype: object

In [5293]: type(series)
Out[5293]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [5294]: type(series[0])
Out[5294]: list
```

Comment: plus 1 for the effort of converting that text to list. :)

Comment: I am kinda new to python ,so please bear with me. I used split() on the text  which converted it to a list. I tried using lambda before, but i got this error

Comment: Before doing split you could have actually used `series.str.count('kids')`

Comment: Yeah, I did. But that  ended up including words other than just kids. Words which included kids, not just kids

Comment: I just realized why i was getting an error with lambda. There were some missing values in the series.

Comment: @IftikarAlam See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501984/4909087).

Answer (score 2):

On your original series, use `str.findall` + `str.len`:

```
print(series)   

0     All of my kids have cried nonstop when
1     We wanted to get something to keep tra
2      My daughter had her 1st baby over a y
3      One of babys first and favorite books
4    Very cute interactive book My son loves

print(series.str.findall(r'\bkids\b'))

0    [kids]
1        []
2        []
3        []
4        []
dtype: object

counts = series.str.findall(r'\bkids\b').str.len()
print(counts)

0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```